# how to get initial parameters during updating a form in Django with TemplateView

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have the following class based TemplateView, I want my TemplateView to be like UpdateView.But I am not very sure where to set the form with the instance parameters. 
 I try it in get_context_data but didn't work. Any ideas ?

```
class ProfileUpdateView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "profile/update_profile.html"

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return super(ProfileUpdateView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profiles/login')

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        try:
            Profile.objects.get(user__id=self.request.user.id)
            user = Profile.objects.get(user__id=self.request.user.id)
            context['profile_form'] = profile_form(data=request.POST, instance=user)
        except:
            context['profile_form'] = ProfileForm(data=self.request.POST)
            context['profile'] = Profile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.id)
            context['experiences'] = Experience.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.id)
            context['education'] = Education.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.id)
            context['award'] = Award.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.id)
            context['publication'] = Publication.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.id)
            context['membership'] = Membership.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.id)
            context['patent'] = Patent.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.id)
            context['certificate'] = Certificate.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.id)
            context['language'] = Language.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.id)
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.POST:
            profile_form = ProfileForm(data=request.POST)
            if profile_form.is_valid():
                profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
                profile.user = request.user
                profile.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: I don't understand, why don't you simply use `UpdateView`?

Comment: Yeah you should use an updateview. If you insist on using a TemplateView, then the get_initial() method is not available and you basically have to manually insert the values from the context in to the form fields on the html template by doing something like this:
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="{{ profile.first_name }}">

Answer (score 1):

Try use CBV(CreateView), and then use `initial` and def `get_initial(self):`

See this [link](https://www.webforefront.com/django/modelclassbasedviews.html), I think this can help you. Section 9-11 and 9-12.